Finding a closed form of the following infinite summation of product of bessel functions
I have asked the same question to math stack exchange, but couldn't get an answer yet. So, I thought maybe it is a good idea to share to here.
While doing my research, I encountered the following infinite series of Bessel functions:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty i^n J_{2n}(x)J_{n}(y).
\end{equation} I have searched around for many different resources, but I still can't figure out.

Here $i=\sqrt{-1}$?

Mathematica cannot do anything with this sum even when $x=y=1$. So, it seems highly unlikely that the requested closed form exists.

Also, you first link leads to the same site as the second one.

Great, thank you for the help!!
